# Can someone please explain this delegate syntax?

Tags: c#

In a class library called DataAccess I find the following declaration and usage:

```
public static class DataAccess
{
    public delegate T LoadObject<T>(SqlDataReader dataReader);

    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> GetDictionaryFromReader<TKey, TValue>(
        Database database
        , DbCommand dbCommand
        , LoadObject<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> loadMethod
        )
    {
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = StoredProcedures.ExecuteSqlDataReader(database, dbCommand))
        {
            GenerateDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dataReader, ref _dictionary, loadMethod);
        }

        return _dictionary;
    }
}
```

**GetDictionaryFromReader above is called by this static method:**

```
public static Dictionary<String, String> GetGroupTypesList()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Database database = CenestDatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

    DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_LIST_GROUP_TYPES);

    dict = DataAccess.GetDictionaryFromReader<string, string>(database, dbCommand, _loadGroupType);

    return dict;
}
```

**It passes "_loadGroupType" into "loadMethod".  "_loadGroupType" looks like this:**

```
private static KeyValuePair<string, string> _loadGroupType(SqlDataReader returnData)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> entry =
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>((string)returnData["Group_Type"], (string)returnData["Group_Type_Desc"]);

    return entry;
}
```

I sort of "get" that the _loadGroupType method is being passed as a parameter into GetDictionaryFromReader.  Okay, but why?  And what is this delegate declaration syntax supposed to say?

```
public delegate T LoadObject<T>(SqlDataReader dataReader);
```

I'd really like to understand what is going on with this.  You don't need to explain it yourself -- but can you point to something that will be able to make it clear to me?

Thanks!

**Additional Note to @ReedCopsey:**

So...

In this using statement:

```
using (SqlDataReader dataReader = StoredProcedures.ExecuteSqlDataReader(database, dbCommand))
{
    GenerateDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dataReader, ref _dictionary, loadMethod);
}
```

Is C# smart enough to recognize that loadMethod needs the SqlDataReader passed to it, and does so -- because of the using statement and the initial delegate declaration?  Because otherwise I can't see how the data reader makes it into the method.

Of course not!  As per @ReedCopsey the GenerateDictionary method uses the SqlDataReader, Duh:

```
private static void GenerateDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    SqlDataReader dataReader
    , ref Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary
    , LoadObject<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> loadMethod
    )
{
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp = loadMethod(dataReader);
        dictionary.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `You don't need to explain it yourself.` yeah, you do. Unless there's another answer on SO that explains it, then link only answers are highly discouraged due to link rot. A question and answer could be viewed years to now, we have to make sure the information doesn't get lost.

Comment: It is a simple mix of delegates and generics. Methods can be generic, so do delegates.

Comment: Well, I'm glad @Mephy believes it is "simple"!  Perhaps it is, and I am a simpleton.  Would not surprise me...

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude, sorry, just that there's no hidden wizardry here. It may be difficult to understand if you're not used to, but it is only generic and delegates, nothing more.

Comment: I didn't take it as rude, sorry about that, @Mephy, I just thought it was amusing, given that it seems quite complex to me.  Maybe this will change (I hope).  I should have put a smiley in there! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And what is this delegate declaration syntax supposed to say?

That is a delegate which is typed to be a method that accepts a `SqlDataReader` as an input, and returns a generic type `T` as the result.

In your case, the `T` result is `KeyValuePair<string,string>`.

---

> Is C# smart enough to recognize that loadMethod needs the SqlDataReader passed to it, and does so -- because of the using statement and the initial delegate declaration? Because otherwise I can't see how the data reader makes it into the method.

No.  The `GenerateDictionary<TKey,TValue>` method is going to use the `dataReader` passed into it to call the delegate.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  So, the generic type T could be any old object instance, depending upon how the delegate is used?

Comment: I believe I see what is going on, finally, and thanks for your help here, but can you address the additional question for clarification I put at the end of the question?  Thanks! :-)

Comment: Oh, shoot, yes.  I didn't scope this out all the way to GenerateDictionary -- and having done so, I see that it did, as you say, use that data reader to pass to loadMethod.  Far out!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `public delegate T LoadObject<T>(SqlDataReader dataReader)` is expecting a `SqlDataReader` and will return whatever type you want it to. Could be an `int`, a `List<string>` or even another delegate. That's because there's no [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the type `T` and it is only associated with the return type of the delegate.

On the other hand, we have `private static KeyValuePair<string, string> _loadGroupType(SqlDataReader returnData)`. This is a function that receives a `SqlDataReader` and returns a... wait, it doesn't matter, could be anything! So the `_loadGroupType` does "match" against the delegate `LoadObject<T>` with `T`=`KeyValuePair<string, string>` and can be implicitly used as such.

If there was a delegate declared such as `delegate KeyValuePair<string, string> D2(SqlDataReader reader);` it would also match, but without the generics this time. When the type doesn't matter for an operation (or it can be contrained), generics are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

First the declaration says: `LoadObject` will be a method that takes an `SqlDataReader` and returns a `T`, where `T` is defined by the user.

Then `GetDictionaryFromReader` says it needs a `LoadObject<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so `T` is `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` here, so it needs a method takes an `SqlDataReader` and returns `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

At last, when you call `GetDictionaryFromReader`, passing `_loadGroupType`, it takes an `SqlDataReader` and returns `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, just fits what `GetDictionaryFromReader` want.

I don't think there is anything diffcult to understand.

Comment: Well, maybe *you* didn't think there was anything difficult to understand, but not all of us are geniuses. :-)  Seriously, this is getting to the bleeding edge of computer science for me.  I'm an old guy.  My brain creaks. +1 for having pity on Methusaleh.